# Logarithmic scale for parametric plot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I would like to introduce a logarithmic scale for the following parametric plot

`ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{y[tau], rr[tau]} /. se6], {tau, 50, 53.5}, 
 PlotRange -> {{990, 998}, {0.6, 0.2}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["R(T)", Below], AxesLabel -> {"T(\[Tau])", ""},
  ImageSize -> 800]`

With the two functions y[tau] and rr[tau] solutions of the same system of differential equations, I would like to plot rr[tau]vs y[tau] . I have tried to transform the result of evaluate to a log scale

`ParametricPlot[{tau,Log[Evaluate[{y[tau], rr[tau]} /. se6]}, {tau, 50, 53.5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["R(T)", Below], AxesLabel -> {"T(\[Tau])", ""},
  ImageSize -> 800]`

but it does not seems to work.

Comment: Often one comes to the logarithmic scale to compress axes, say, if the latter cover several orders of magnitude. In your case the x coordinate spans over 8 units, while the y coordinate - over 0.4 units. Are you sure that you need to go to logarithmic scale? If yes, try this: `ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{Log[y[tau]], Log[rr[tau]]} /. se6], {tau, 50, 53.5}, 
 PlotRange -> {{990, 998}, {0.2, 0.6}}]`.